# Copying Data Bar Formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a variety of rows with different values that need to be compared to one another:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1       84      90      75
1       90      65      89
```

I want data bar formatting on each row so that the data bar formatting only considers values in the specific row. E.g in Row 1, the data bar for Col3 will be full while the other data bars will be less than full, as Col3 is the highest value and the other bars should reflect the cell value compared to this.

I can't do this manually row per row as I have too many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution that should work for you. You would have to adjust the following statements:

Set myRange = Columns("B:D") <--- On what columns do you want the macro to operate?

For i = 2 To 3 <--- ...and on what rows?

```
Sub FormatRows()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Columns("B:D")

For i = 2 To 3
Rows(i).Columns("B:D").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).ShowValue = True
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
        .Color = 13012579
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).AxisColor
        .Color = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Next i
End Sub
```